# ALINEAR ICONOS fa fa-truck

Tags: html

Buenos Noches estoy intentando alinear con HTML tres iconos uno al lado del otro y no puedo lograrlo los iconos me salen uno debajo del otro y los quiero de la forma siguiente:

icono de comunicación                        icono de truck                   icono de dollar

Comment: A tu pregunta le hace falta el código mínimo necesario para observar el problema y poderte ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es alinearlos horizontalmente al centro debes usar un contenedor `<div>` para indicarle la orientación de los iconos:

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 60px;
}
.bloque_centro {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bloque_centro">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
<i href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
<i href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</div>
```

Si lo que quieres es alinearlo a la izquierda o derecha debes cambiar el `text-align: center` del `<div>` por la justificación que quieras: `left` o `right`.

**Para tu caso concreto edito la respuesta, siendo esto:**
No debes utiliza figure, más recomendable utilizar contenedores div y moverlos.
Lo que hacemos es crear un bloque principal para contener a los otros dos bloques llamados bloque1 y bloque2 que serán los que estarán alineados horizontalmente justificados a la izquierda. Si quieres que queden horizontalmente centrados debes cambiar el `text-aling:left;` del `.bloque_centro` y ponerlo `text-align:center;`

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 60px;
}
.bloque_centro {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.bloque1, .bloque2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bloque_centro">
  <div class="bloque1"> 
<i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
<h3> ENTREGA... </h3> 
<p>RECOGIDA... 10AM Y 4PM </p> 
  </div> 

  <div class="bloque2"> 
<i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
<h3> ENTREGA... </h3> 
<p>RECOGIDA... 10AM Y 4PM </p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias y disculpa este es mi código que estoy haciendo mal quiero entender  <figure>

<i class = "fa fa-truck"> </i>

</figure>

<div class = "payment-info">

<h3> ENTREGA Y RECOGIDA EN CASA </h3>

<p>RECOGIDA Y ENTRAGA  10AM Y 4PM  </p>

</div>
<figure>

<i class = "fa fa-truck" aria-raight="true"> </i>

</figure>

<div class = "payment-info">

<h3> ENTREGA Y RECOGIDA EN CASA </h3>

<p>RECOGIDA Y ENTRAGA  10AM Y 4PM  </p>

</div>

Comment: Esto lo estoy editando en un widget de texto en wordpres

Comment: Ya he actualizado el código

Comment: Gracias y disculpa por no darme cuenta antes este widget solo acepta HTML ya que cuando coloco este código en el widget la parte de css en la pagina se lee o se ve esa parte del codigo en la web

Comment: ¿Te ha servido la respuesta?

Comment: Buenos dias Jok en el widjet no me funciona ya que solo acepta HTML ya que cuando coloco este código en el widget la parte de css en la pagina se lee o se ve esa parte del codigo en la web –

Comment: Añade el css en style.css o en Personalizar > Custom CSS

Comment: Gracias caso resuelto les agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: Me alegro. Si te ha servido la respuesta márcala como resuelta. Gracias!